# How do I recover from committing a git project before committing the submodule?

Tags: git, commit, git-submodules

I have a project in a git repository, with a git submodule. I made changes to both the project and the submodule, and committed the project.

Apparently I was supposed to commit the submodule first, then commit the project. Next time I'll do that.

In the meantime, how do I recover?

Answer (score 0):

You can use git reset HEAD~1 to return to the state before the commit.